# Clear IntelliJ console from java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to clear IntelliJ console from code? I've tried all the solutions I've found, like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear")
System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
System.out.flush();
```

even printing a lot of "\b"s just prints a odd char instead of erasing the output.
Printing a lot of "\n" doesn't work for me, for two reasons:

1. you are still able to scroll up;
2. pointer is not placed at the beginning of the console.

I just need to trigger the console "Clear All" button (the little trashcan icon), but from within the code. Every hack is well accepted.

Comment: try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");`

Comment: Thank for the answer. I think "cls" is a command for Windows, the equivalent of "clear" in UNIX; that solution is not working.

Comment: A moderator deleted my answer that Grep Console plugin supports it now...

Answer (score 5):

I "hacked" it by literally clicking the "Clear All" icon:

```
public static void click(int x, int y) throws AWTException{
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(x, y);
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

calling this with these coordinates on my screen:

```
click(75,890);
```

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA console is not a real terminal, so there is no command to clear it from your Java code.

Try run your application in other console and you can make a function like this:

```
public static void ClearConsole(){
    try{
        String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name") //Check the current operating system
          
        if(operatingSystem.contains("Windows")){        
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls");
            Process startProcess = pb.inheritIO.start();
            startProcess.waitFor();
        } else {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("clear");
            Process startProcess = pb.inheritIO.start();

            startProcess.waitFor();
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```